# matplotlib. Rellenar de color áreas por encima o por debajo de una recta

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

Con la función siguiente

```
import pandas as pd
import talib as ta
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_data_with_adx(data):
    # Calcula las SMA
    data['SMA1'] = data['Close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
    data['SMA2'] = data['Close'].rolling(window=50).mean()
    
    # Calcula el Average Directional Index (ADX)
    adx = ta.ADX(data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'], timeperiod=14)

    # Crea la figura y los ejes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 8))
    
    # Grafica la data en el primer eje
    ax[0].plot(data.index, data['Close'], label='Close')
    ax[0].plot(data.index, data['SMA1'], label='SMA1')
    ax[0].plot(data.index, data['SMA2'], label='SMA2')
    ax[0].set_ylabel('Price')
    ax[0].legend()

    # Grafica el ADX en el segundo eje
    ax[1].plot(data.index, adx, label='ADX')
    ax[1].axhline(y=25, color='r', linestyle='--', label='Upper Reference Level')
    ax[1].axhline(y=40, color='g', linestyle='--', label='Lower Reference Level')
    ax[1].set_ylabel('ADX')
    ax[1].legend()

    # Rellena entre los límites superior e inferior y el ADX
    ax[1].fill_between(data.index, adx, 25, where=adx>=25, facecolor='green', alpha=0.3)
    ax[1].fill_between(data.index, adx, 20, where=(adx>=20) & (adx<25), facecolor='blue', alpha=0.3)
    ax[1].fill_between(data.index, adx, 20, where=adx<20, facecolor='red', alpha=0.3)
    
    plt.show()

ticker = 'AAA'
df = yf.download(ticker, start='2016-1-4' , end='2022-12-31', progress=False)
plot_data_with_adx(df)
```

Prtendo rellenar: de verde, superficies entre el límite superior y la parte de la curva ADX por encima de éste límite. De azul, la paarte de la curava ADX entre los dos límites. Y de rojo, la parte de la curva ADX, por debajo del límite inferior. Me devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo se puede ver, no es lo que yo quiero. ¿Cuál es mi error?.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía mal definidos los límites. Queda así.

```
# Rellena entre los límites superior e inferior y el ADX
axs[1].fill_between(self.data.index, self.adx, 40, where=self.adx>=40, facecolor='green', alpha=0.3)
axs[1].fill_between(self.data.index, self.adx, 25, self.adx , 40, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.1)
axs[1].fill_between(self.data.index, self.adx, 25, where=self.adx<25, facecolor='red', alpha=0.3)
```

Color verde entre los límites: línea de adx 40 y valores de adx mayores de 40.
Color azul: valores de adx mayores de 25 y menores 40.
Color rojo por debajo de la línea de 25 yentre los valores de adx menores de 25